# Getting error while posting the data using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting the following error while posting the data via REST API through Postman using Node.js. I am providing my code below.

server.js:

```
 var express=require('express');
    var morgan = require('morgan');
    var http=require('http');
    var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
    var methodOverride = require('method-override');
    var mongo = require('mongojs');
    var app=express();
    var server=http.Server(app);
    var port=8080;
    require('./route/route.js')(app);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));     // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
    app.use(morgan('dev'));                     // log every request to the console
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false,limit: '5mb' }))    // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}))    // parse application/json
    app.use(methodOverride());                  // simulate DELETE and PUT
    app.get('/',function(req,res){
        res.json({"message": "Task management application."});
    })
    server.listen(port);
    console.log("Server is running on the port"+port);
```

route/route.js:

```
var task=require('../controller/controller.js');
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.post('/signup',task.userSignup);
}
```

controller/controller.js:

```
var mongoJs=require('mongojs');
var database='TASK';
var collections=['f_users'];
var db=mongoJs("127.0.0.1:27017/"+database, collections);
db.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('database connected')
});
exports.userSignup=function(req,res){
    console.log('req',req);
    var username=req.body.username;
    var password=req.body.password;
    var phone=req.body.phone;
    db.f_users.insert({'username':username,'password':password,'phone':phone},function(err,docs){
        if (!err) {
            if (docs) {
                res.json({'message':'User has registered successfully'});
            }
        }
    })
}
```

I am doing the post like below.

[image]

Here I am getting the following error while posting the data.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;username&#39; of undefined
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at exports.userSignup (C:\xampp\htdocs\bigdata\controller\controller.js:10:23)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\bigdata\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\bigdata\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Route.dispatch (C:\xampp\htdocs\bigdata\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\bigdata\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\xampp\htdocs\bigdata\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (C:\xampp\htdocs\bigdata\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\bigdata\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at expressInit (C:\xampp\htdocs\bigdata\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:33:5)
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\bigdata\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

How can I resolve this error and save the data successfully?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32617920/6702495

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling POST submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617610/handling-post-submission)